# Serialize different objects to the same XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

As the title implies, the idea is to use 1 XML to store serialization/values for different objects types. Right now I was able to serialize my objects and I defined its root element and properties on the class itself - by using XmlRoot property on the class - But I don't understand exactly how I can tell the XmlSerializer or XmlWriter to APPEND to an existing XML (or create if not exist) but not overwrite.

The final goal is to have 5 objects (classes) and 1 dataset stored on the same XML and not use different ones, is it possible?

Update: My idea is to have each object in its own root element, so they not share roots

Right now I am using this code to write my serialized class

```
var sts = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true, OmitXmlDeclaration = true, };
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClassName));
var filename = "whatever.xml";
XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(filename, sts);
xs.Serialize(w, objReference);
w.Close();
```

And for writing my dataset I simply call the WriteXml method of it.

```
var filename = "whatever.xml";
myDataSet.myTable.WriteXml(filename, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
```

Comment: why not create a container class, containing those 5 classes? eg. https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZTYwY6 - and use the container class to serialize/deserialize ?!?

Comment: see this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mM5USZ - note that the second output will have 2 items in

Comment: A Well formed XML has only one root element.  If you append to a well formed XML you have to open existing XML and add new data inside the open/close tags.  Many systems that create a log file using XML format do not use well formed xml and simply add new data to end of file.  You then have an array of elements at the root instead of one element.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, but it's not a very good idea.

#### Write multiple objects into one file

First, what you would want to do would look something like this:

```cs
namespace MyProgram;

public class Program
{
    public class Person
    {
        public required string Name { get; set; }
        public required int Age { get; set; }
    }

    public class Plane
    {
        public required int NumberOfPassengers { get; set; }
        public required int NumberOfCrewMembers { get; set; }
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var person1 = new Person
        {
            Name = "Thomas",
            Age = 23
        };
        var person2 = new Person
        {
            Name = "John",
            Age = 52
        };
        var plane = new Plane
        {
            NumberOfPassengers = 368,
            NumberOfCrewMembers = 24
        };
        // Create serializer for different types
        var personSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
        var planeSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Plane));

        // Open up a file stream
        using var fileStream = File.Open("./allInOne.xml", FileMode.Create);

        // Serialize diffent objects to that file stream 
        personSerializer.Serialize(fileStream, person1);
        planeSerializer.Serialize(fileStream, plane);
        personSerializer.Serialize(fileStream, person2);
    }
}
```

This will result in the following `allInOne.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>Thomas</Name>
  <Age>23</Age>
</Person><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Plane xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <NumberOfPassengers>368</NumberOfPassengers>
  <NumberOfCrewMembers>24</NumberOfCrewMembers>
</Plane><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Age>52</Age>
</Person>
```

As you can see this more or less just different XML files appended and it's very complex to deserialize again, as you need to open the `FileStream`, read till you encounter the XML declaration, then find out which type of object it is and then you can deserialize. So you shouldn't do that.

Also please note that this is technically not a valid XML file as they should only have one root element, here you have multiple (even if you remove the XML declaration in between). This is just meant to be a demo to show you that yes, you could theoretically do that.

#### Other options

##### "Composite object"

You could create an object which contains everything you need to store and then just (de-)serialize that.

```cs
namespace MyProgram;

public class Program
{
    public class Person
    {
        public required string Name { get; set; }
        public required int Age { get; set; }
    }

    public class Plane
    {
        public required int NumberOfPassengers { get; set; }
        public required int NumberOfCrewMembers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Composite
    {
        public required Person Person1 { get; set; }
        public required Plane Plane { get; set; }
        public required Person Person2 { get; set; }
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var person1 = new Person
        {
            Name = "Thomas",
            Age = 23
        };
        var person2 = new Person
        {
            Name = "John",
            Age = 52
        };
        var plane = new Plane
        {
            NumberOfPassengers = 368,
            NumberOfCrewMembers = 24
        };
        var composite = new Composite
        {
            Person1 = person1,
            Person2 = person2,
            Plane = plane
        };
        // Create serializer for different types
        var compositeSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Composite));

        // Open up a file stream
        using var fileStream = File.Open("./composite.xml", FileMode.Create);

        // Serialize diffent objects to that file stream 
        compositeSerializer.Serialize(fileStream, composite);

        // Go back to start of stream
        fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        // Deserialize again
        var deserialized = (Composite)compositeSerializer.Deserialize(fileStream)!;
        Console.WriteLine(deserialized.Person1.Name);
    }
}
```

> Obviously you'd probably have `List<Person>` or `List<Plane>` but this is just to illustrate the idea.

##### Repository pattern

Another option, which I would recommend you use is to use the [repository pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-design#the-repository-pattern) where you don't mix different types into one storage and you'll have some decoupling between the actual storage implementation (here an XML file) which might change over time (e.g. using JSON or a database instead) and your application logic.

Comment: well, I agree with you that it doesn't look like a good idea, because both Plane and Person are root elements right? I was assuming It would like like <Persons>...</Persons> and then <Planes>...</Planes> , so you can distinguish each section